# Working of ant's property - tricky & alternate way to handle

Tags: ant, properties, ant-contrib

Working with simple ant's property is tricky & doesn't allow to set needed value easily (properties are immutable).  Using ant-conrib's var tasks allows properties to be set and unset.

Any genuinue or good reason behind making ant property designed to work in such a complex way?.

```
<property name="some.ant.prop" value=""/>

        <if>
            <isset property="some.ant.prop"/>
            <then>
                <echo message="immutable ant prop - not good, defined and just even set to null string : ${some.ant.prop}"/>

                <property name="some.ant.prop" value="no-effect-value"/>
                <echo message="no-effect on changing already defined prop : ${some.ant.prop}"/>

                <var name="some.ant.prop" unset="true"/>
                <property name="some.ant.prop" value="any-value-accepted"/>
                <echo message="Overwritten prop value: ${some.ant.prop}"/>

            </then>
        </if>
```

Not for discussion or argument , but its good to know on more feasible alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ant ain't a programming language !
Properties once set are immutable in ant by design.
The Pros and Cons have been discussed (much too) often and i won't go into details.

Several possibilities to get over those limitations :
In the past people used antcall for that purpose - with all its drawbacks, search for 'antcall vs. macrodef' to get the details. Ant 1.6 introduced `macrodef` and Ant 1.8 came with a new `local` task.
If macrodef and local are not sufficient you may use script task with builtin javascript engine (since JDK 1.6) or [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) to access ant api.
There are also Ant addons like f.e. antcontrib or [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/). If antcontrib var / unset feels too clumsy for you, the
Flaka's `let` task provides a more straight approach for overwriting properties :

```
<!-- set a new property -->
<fl:let>foo := 'bar'</fl:let>

<!-- overwrite an existing property or userproperty
     (those properties defined on the commandline via -Dfoo=bar ..)
     notice the double '::' in foo ::= 'baz' -->
<fl:let>foo ::= 'baz'</fl:let>
```

Finally : 
Either get used to ant and its limitations (**but don't use antcall !**) or
use Ant addon
 [use ant from groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy)
 or switch to [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).